# Unable to read data from Redshift with column names having space

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

Currently I am facing one issue regarding reading the data into Python from redshift connection. I am able to connect to redshift server from Python and also able to fetch the data.

Problem is coming while applying the filter on the column name having "spaces" in between. I have tried several combinations to get the filtered data through query, but no outcome.

Here is the code snippet I am using to connect Python to redshift server.

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect(dbname= 'dbname', host='hostname', port= 'portnumber', 
                                     user= 'username', password= 'password')
query = "select * from schema.table_name WHERE schema.table_name.part number='123456'
df = pd.read_sql(query, con)
```

In the above code, I want to get data only for "part number" = "123456". But due to space in between , I am getting error. I also tried combinations like [part number] , 'part number' , {part number} , (part number).

Need your support to find any work around for this problem.

Comment: This is why using spaces in column names is *always* a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
query = "select * from schema.table_name WHERE schema.table_name.\"part number\"='123456';"
```

or just

```
query = "select * from schema.table_name WHERE \"part number\"='123456';"
```